# CARTO weighted heatmap with variable range per point

Tags: carto, heat-map, cartocss, torque

I'm trying to do a Heatmap with carto but seems that torque considers each point equal in covered range but my data consists in values from antennas that cover different ranges (and i need that granularity).

Is this possible? Do I have to preprocess my data or use another tool?

I tried to draw every point instead of using torque but then I've got graphical glitches on the zoom

[image: Graphical glitches]

Carto CSS for that:

```
#heatmap {
  image-filters: colorize-alpha(blue, cyan, lightgreen, yellow , orange, red);
  marker-file: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.cartodb.assets.static/alphamarker.png);
  marker-allow-overlap: true;

  [value > 1] {
    marker-opacity: 0;
  }
  [value > 10] {
    marker-opacity: 0.2
  }
  [value > 100] {
    marker-opacity: 0.4
  }
  [value > 1000] {
    marker-opacity: 0.8
  }
  [value > 10000] {
    marker-opacity: 1
  }

  [zoom>=0] {
    marker-width: [range] * 1;
  }
  [zoom>=1] {
    marker-width: [range] * 2; 
  }
  [zoom>=2] {
    marker-width: [range] * 4;
  }
  [zoom>=3] {
    marker-width: [range] * 8;
  }
  [zoom>=4] {
    marker-width: [range] * 16;
  }
  [zoom>=5] {
    marker-width: [range] * 32;
  }
  [zoom>=6] {
    marker-width: [range] * 64;
  }
  [zoom>=7] {
    marker-width: [range] * 128;
  }
  [zoom>=8] {
    marker-width: [range] * 256;
  }
  [zoom>=9] {
    marker-width: [range] * 512;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Editor (old UI) or BUILDER (new UI)?

Comment: I'm using the old UI but i think that i can change it!